# Illegal string offset php

Tags: php, arrays, string, key, markup

I have been fighting this issue and actually solved it once, but still do not understand what is the issue here. I keep on running into "Illegal string offset" . Ok yes i have an array. Yes it does have keys, that I am trying to access, and values for some key are in fact strings. For some magic reason everything works in one place and does not in the other.  Also, what is interesting is that when  I try to var dump a part of an array everything looks fine (maybe due to lack of knowledge).

Thank You for your help in advance! Please try to explain in simple terms. I once had a guy who rewrote my code entirely . It's great, but i am trying to learn and he just gave me a peace of a cake too big for me to bite.

Here is the code *The part that echoes out the code is at the bottom of this block below.

```
$artists = get_artists_all();

foreach ($artists as $artists_id => $artist) {

        if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
            $artists_id = $_GET["id"];
                if(isset($artists["$artists_id"])){
                $artist = $artists[$artists_id];
            }
        }
        if (!isset($artist)){
            header("Location:".BASE_URL."artists/");
            exit();
        }

    foreach ($artist as $work) {

        if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
            $artist_id = $_GET["id"];
                if(isset($artist["$artist_id"])){
                $work = $artist[$artist_id]["id"];
                }
        }
        if (!isset($work)){
            header("Location:".BASE_URL."artist/");
            exit();

        }
    }   
          }

echo "<ul>";
foreach ($artist as $work){

    echo "<pre>";
    echo $work["name"] . "\n";
    echo $work["title"];
    echo "</pre>";

}
echo '</ul>';
```

Here is the error I get. Notice, that despite the error it still shows the desired information

> Warning:  Illegal string offset 'name' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\artists\artist.php on line 52
>
> A
>
> Warning:  Illegal string offset 'title' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\artists\artist.php on line 53
>
> A Anatoly Zverev "Portrait of Vladimir Nemukhin" Anatoly Zverev
>   "Sunset" Anatoly Zverev "Young Woman"

And last but not least part of the array I am working with.

```
$zverev = array(
    "name" => "Anatoly Zverev",
    $zverev[] = array(
        "name" => "Anatoly Zverev",
        "title" => '"'."Portrait of Vladimir Nemukhin".'"',
        "year" => 1982,
        "media" => "Mixed media on paper",
        "dimentions" => "H:" . 18.5 . " x W:" . 14 . "in",
        "availability" => "Sold",
        "thumb" => IMG_PATH . "anatoly_zverev".THUMB_PATH. "Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Portrait_Vladimir_Nemukhin.jpg",
        "lg" => IMG_PATH . "anatoly_zverev" . LG_PATH ."Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Portrait_Vladimir_Nemukhin.jpg"
        ),
    $zverev[] = array(
        "name" => "Anatoly Zverev",
        "title" => '"'."Sunset".'"',
        "year" => 1980,
        "media" => "Mixed media on paper",
        "dimentions" => "H:" . 33.7 . " x W:" . 24 . "in",
        "availability" => $available,
        "thumb" => IMG_PATH . "anatoly_zverev".THUMB_PATH. "Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Sunset.jpg",
        "lg" => IMG_PATH . "anatoly_zverev" . LG_PATH ."Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Sunset.jpg"
        ),
    $zverev[] = array(
        "name" => "Anatoly Zverev",
        "title" => '"'."Young Woman".'"',
        "year" => 1966,
        "media" => "Ink on paper",
        "dimentions" => "H:" . 16 . " x W:" . 11.2 . "in",
        "availability" => $available,
        "thumb" => IMG_PATH . "anatoly_zverev".THUMB_PATH. "Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Young_Woman.jpg",
        "lg" => IMG_PATH . "anatoly_zverev" . LG_PATH ."Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Young_Woman.jpg"
        )
        ),
```

As per request var_dump($artist) .... Weird, but it cycles through this part of the array 3 times

> 

```
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(31) ""Portrait of Vladimir Nemukhin""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1982)
    ["media"]=>
    string(20) "Mixed media on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:18.5 x W:14in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(4) "Sold"
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(87) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Portrait_Vladimir_Nemukhin.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(84) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Portrait_Vladimir_Nemukhin.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) ""Sunset""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1980)
    ["media"]=>
    string(20) "Mixed media on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:33.7 x W:24in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(10) "/contact/""
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(67) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Sunset.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(64) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Sunset.jpg"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) ""Young Woman""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1966)
    ["media"]=>
    string(12) "Ink on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:16 x W:11.2in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(10) "/contact/""
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(72) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Young_Woman.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(69) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Young_Woman.jpg"
  }
  ["id"]=>
  int(46)
}
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(31) ""Portrait of Vladimir Nemukhin""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1982)
    ["media"]=>
    string(20) "Mixed media on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:18.5 x W:14in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(4) "Sold"
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(87) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Portrait_Vladimir_Nemukhin.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(84) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Portrait_Vladimir_Nemukhin.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) ""Sunset""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1980)
    ["media"]=>
    string(20) "Mixed media on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:33.7 x W:24in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(10) "/contact/""
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(67) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Sunset.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(64) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Sunset.jpg"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) ""Young Woman""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1966)
    ["media"]=>
    string(12) "Ink on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:16 x W:11.2in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(10) "/contact/""
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(72) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Young_Woman.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(69) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Young_Woman.jpg"
  }
  ["id"]=>
  int(46)
}
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(31) ""Portrait of Vladimir Nemukhin""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1982)
    ["media"]=>
    string(20) "Mixed media on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:18.5 x W:14in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(4) "Sold"
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(87) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Portrait_Vladimir_Nemukhin.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(84) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Portrait_Vladimir_Nemukhin.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) ""Sunset""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1980)
    ["media"]=>
    string(20) "Mixed media on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:33.7 x W:24in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(10) "/contact/""
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(67) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Sunset.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(64) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Sunset.jpg"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) ""Young Woman""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1966)
    ["media"]=>
    string(12) "Ink on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:16 x W:11.2in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(10) "/contact/""
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(72) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Young_Woman.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(69) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Young_Woman.jpg"
  }
  ["id"]=>
  int(46)
}
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(31) ""Portrait of Vladimir Nemukhin""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1982)
    ["media"]=>
    string(20) "Mixed media on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:18.5 x W:14in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(4) "Sold"
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(87) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Portrait_Vladimir_Nemukhin.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(84) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Portrait_Vladimir_Nemukhin.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) ""Sunset""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1980)
    ["media"]=>
    string(20) "Mixed media on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:33.7 x W:24in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(10) "/contact/""
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(67) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Sunset.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(64) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Sunset.jpg"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) ""Young Woman""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1966)
    ["media"]=>
    string(12) "Ink on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:16 x W:11.2in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(10) "/contact/""
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(72) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Young_Woman.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(69) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Young_Woman.jpg"
  }
  ["id"]=>
  int(46)
}
array(5) {
  ["name"]=>
  string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
  [0]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(31) ""Portrait of Vladimir Nemukhin""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1982)
    ["media"]=>
    string(20) "Mixed media on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:18.5 x W:14in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(4) "Sold"
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(87) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Portrait_Vladimir_Nemukhin.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(84) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Portrait_Vladimir_Nemukhin.jpg"
  }
  [1]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(8) ""Sunset""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1980)
    ["media"]=>
    string(20) "Mixed media on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:33.7 x W:24in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(10) "/contact/""
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(67) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Sunset.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(64) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Sunset.jpg"
  }
  [2]=>
  array(8) {
    ["name"]=>
    string(14) "Anatoly Zverev"
    ["title"]=>
    string(13) ""Young Woman""
    ["year"]=>
    int(1966)
    ["media"]=>
    string(12) "Ink on paper"
    ["dimentions"]=>
    string(15) "H:16 x W:11.2in"
    ["availability"]=>
    string(10) "/contact/""
    ["thumb"]=>
    string(72) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/ldpi/Thumb_Anatoly_Zverev_Young_Woman.jpg"
    ["lg"]=>
    string(69) "/artists/anatoly_zverev/images/mdpi/Lg_Anatoly_Zverev_Young_Woman.jpg"
  }
  ["id"]=>
  int(46)
}
```

Comment: Where is the definition for  
    get_artists_all();

Comment: Can you do var_dump() on $artist and put it here?

Comment: It'd be helpful if you pointed out WHICH of all those lines is actually line 52. but as the error states, you're using an illegal string offset, meaning you're trying to access a string as if it was an array (which is normally ok), but using a key which can NOT be mapped to an integer. e.g. `$foo = 'foo'; echo $foo[array()]` would cause this error.

Comment: QA means not "Can you debug my code?"

Comment: I dont ask to debug it. I posted code for reference. So i could get an answer based on what I think i wrapped my head around ie saving time on trying to understand an answer from an analogy.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your first foreach loop;

```
foreach ($artist as $work) {

    if (isset($_GET["id"])) {
        $artist_id = $_GET["id"];
            if(isset($artist["$artist_id"])){
            $work = $artist[$artist_id]["id"];
            }
    }
    if (!isset($work)){
        header("Location:".BASE_URL."artist/");
        exit();

    }
```

You have said that "For each of the $artist variable, use the variable $work", but within that loop, you are still referencing as $artist and not $work.